# Reset The State on React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, state

Assuming that I have a variable called "NAME", that variable has a stored name, I also have this variable in my State, lets say that variable has stored 'JOSH'

```
this.state = {
nombre: ' '
}
```

I set this variable in an input value, so when i clic in a button, puts in the input value the variable "NAME", so it shows me in the input "JOSH"

If I delete a letter or the whole field by mistake, with a button of "UNDO", i should revert the changes, so when there's "JOSH" in the input, and delete 1 letter (JOS), when i clic the button UNDO, it should bring me again "JOSH".

Here my doubt is, **how do I reset the state to the original value ?**

I'm thinking of something like...:

`this.setSate ({name});` but something fails me here that doesn't undo it

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking; wouldn't you just need to keep an "undo" stack of previous values (or a single value if you don't need multiple levels of undo)?

Comment: Do you want `state` to change as you change value in the input field?

Comment: Maybe you need to store each state changes for that particular variable in a history array for example, so you can revert it back with your undo button by accessing `arrayLength - 1` indexed value from the array. But I'm just guessing here.

Answer (score 1):

When updating the state, keep track of all previous states:

```
 this.state = { name: '', history: [] };

 // whe  adding name:
 this.setState(({ history, name: oldName }) => ({ name, history: [...history, oldName] }));
```

then later you can easily restore the previous state:

```
this.setState(({ history }) => ({ name: history[history.length - 1] || '', history: history.slice(0, -1) }));
```